# How to configure python virtual step for hadoop in ami 4.x

Tags: virtualenv, amazon-emr, amazon-ami

In ami 3 the file `/home/hadoop/conf/hadoop-user-env.sh` existed. And this legacy code I'm looking at was able to run this command in bootstrapping.

```
echo ". /home/hadoop/resources/pips/bin/activate" >> /home/hadoop/conf/hadoop-user-env.sh
```

This activates virtual env for Python.

In ami 4 this file is gone. How am I suppose to get a python step in Hadoop to run in virtual env under ami 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to give this a shot and hope it helps you.

In Amazon EMR AMI versions 2.x and 3.x, there was a hadoop-user-env.sh script which was not part of standard Hadoop and was used along with the configure-daemons bootstrap action to configure the Hadoop environment. The script included the following actions:

```
#!/bin/bash 
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true; 
echo "HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/my.jar" >> /home/hadoop/conf/hadoop-user-env.sh
```

In Amazon EMR release 4.x, you can do the same now with the hadoop-env configurations:

```
[ 
  { 
     "Classification":"hadoop-env",
     "Properties":{ 

     },
     "Configurations":[ 
        { 
           "Classification":"export",
           "Properties":{ 
              "HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST":"true",
              "HADOOP_CLASSPATH":"/path/to/my.jar"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

There is more info about the differences and replacement codes on [Amazon's Documentation Site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.7.2/emr-release-differences.html#release-differences-bootstrap).